# Как вернуть переменным такое же значение, которое было в начале программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

у меня есть пять переменных,(k, list1, btn, square, whowin2) которые при использовании функции restart1 должны стать такими же, какими они были изначально.

```
def restart1(k, list1, var, vr):
    k = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    for q in range(0, 8):
        btn[q].config( root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[q], command = lambda: xstroke(k, int(q)+1), width=4, height=1)
    var.set('Начинай игру!\n Можешь нажать на свободную \n кнопку, чтобы поставить "X"!')
    vr.set("  \(^ I ^)/  ")
    return k, btn, list1

btn=[Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[0], command = lambda: xstroke(k, int(1)), width=4,height=1), Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[1], command = lambda: xstroke(k, int(2)), width=4,height=1),
     Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[2], command = lambda: xstroke(k, int(3)), width=4,height=1), Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[3], command = lambda: xstroke(k, int(4)), width=4,height=1),
     Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[4], command = lambda: xstroke(k, int(5)), width=4,height=1), Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[5], command = lambda: xstroke(k, int(6)), width=4,height=1),
     Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[6], command = lambda: xstroke(k, int(7)), width=4,height=1), Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[7], command = lambda: xstroke(k, int(8)), width=4,height=1),
     Button(root, bg="#87CEFA", text = k[8], command = lambda: xstroke(k, int(9)), width=4,height=1)]
k = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
var = StringVar()
square = Label(root, textvariable=var, relief=RAISED, height=9, width=30, bg = '#B404AE', fg='white')
var.set('текст1')
square.pack()
square.place(x=430,y=60)

vr = StringVar()
whowin2 = Label(root, textvariable=vr, relief=RAISED, height=2, width=12, bg = '#87CEFA', fg='black')

vr.set("  \(^ I ^)/  ")
whowin2.pack()
whowin2.place(x=278,y=15)
```

Comment: Сохраните эти значения в других переменных и потом восстановите из них

Answer (score 1):

Можете просто передавать аргументы списка в функцию и делать в этой функции хоть что, или как уже сказал [@vp_atrh](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/827125/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B#comment1319705_827125) просто добавить еще одну переменную и ссылаться потом на нее

Пример где вы посылаете аргументы списка `k` после чего их переворачиваете их порядок задом на перед и обратно:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    step = True

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.k = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
        self.btn = [tk.Button(self, bg="#87CEFA", text=self.k[0], width=4, height=1),
                    tk.Button(self, bg="#87CEFA", text=self.k[1], width=4, height=1),
                    tk.Button(self, bg="#87CEFA", text=self.k[2], width=4, height=1),
                    tk.Button(self, bg="#87CEFA", text=self.k[3], width=4, height=1),
                    tk.Button(self, bg="#87CEFA", text=self.k[4], width=4, height=1),
                    tk.Button(self, bg="#87CEFA", text=self.k[5], width=4, height=1),
                    tk.Button(self, bg="#87CEFA", text=self.k[6], width=4, height=1),
                    tk.Button(self, bg="#87CEFA", text=self.k[7], width=4, height=1),
                    tk.Button(self, bg="#87CEFA", text=self.k[8], width=4, height=1)]
        for i in self.btn:
            i.pack()
        but = tk.Button(self, bg="#87CEFA", text="Нажми", command=lambda: self.func(self.k))
        but.pack()

    def func(self, value):
        if self.step:
            result = value[::-1]
            for num, i in enumerate(self.btn):
                i["text"] = result[num]
            self.step = False
        else:
            for num, i in enumerate(self.btn):
                i["text"] = self.k[num]
            self.step = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]